# Do Christians who view homosexuality as a sin believe that homosexuals can be freed from their sinful condition by the power of God?

Tags: sin, pneumatology, homosexuality, sanctification

It should be common sense knowledge that many Christians condemn homosexuality as a sin. The following already asked questions should be more than enough to prove the point:

- [Why do some Christians believe it is moral to be a homosexual?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/381/why-do-some-christians-believe-it-is-moral-to-be-a-homosexual)
- [What is the Biblical argument that homosexual attraction is sinful by itself?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35233/what-is-the-biblical-argument-that-homosexual-attraction-is-sinful-by-itself)
- [What is a Christian's justification for a legal prohibition of homosexual marriage?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7598/what-is-a-christians-justification-for-a-legal-prohibition-of-homosexual-marria)

That said, I'm not sure if I've ever heard Christians who claim that homosexuality is a sin also claim that homosexuals can be freed from their (claimed) sinful condition. Logic tells me that they should expect this to be the case, in light of passages such as:

Romans 8:12-17 (ESV):

> 12 So then, brothers, we are debtors, not to the flesh, to live according to the flesh. 13 For if you live according to the flesh you will die, **but if by the Spirit you put to death the deeds of the body, you will live**. 14 For all who are led by the Spirit of God are sons of God. 15 For you did not receive the spirit of slavery to fall back into fear, but you have received the Spirit of adoption as sons, by whom we cry, “Abba! Father!” 16 The Spirit himself bears witness with our spirit that we are children of God, 17 and if children, then heirs—heirs of God and fellow heirs with Christ, provided we suffer with him in order that we may also be glorified with him.

Galatians 5:16-24 (ESV):

> 16 But I say, **walk by the Spirit, and you will not gratify the desires of the flesh**. 17 For the desires of the flesh are against the Spirit, and the desires of the Spirit are against the flesh, for these are opposed to each other, to keep you from doing the things you want to do. 18 But if you are led by the Spirit, you are not under the law. 19 **Now the works of the flesh are evident: sexual immorality**, impurity, sensuality, 20 idolatry, sorcery, enmity, strife, jealousy, fits of anger, rivalries, dissensions, divisions, 21 envy, drunkenness, orgies, and things like these. I warn you, as I warned you before, that those who do such things will not inherit the kingdom of God. 22 **But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, patience, kindness, goodness, faithfulness**, 23 **gentleness, self-control**; against such things there is no law. 24 **And those who belong to Christ Jesus have crucified the flesh with its passions and desires**.

If homosexuality is a sinful desire of the flesh, as many Christians believe, does this mean that homosexuality, as any other sin, can be reversed by the power of God, through the Holy Spirit, as the passages above seem to indicate? Is this the standard view among Christians who condemn homosexuality as a sin?

An alternative way of phrasing the question: Can God heal homosexuality (according to those who view homosexuality as a sin)?

Comment: Well, God is omnipotent, so anything is possible. In general, I would expect the answer is the same as any other sinful desire. Can an alcoholic be freed from alcoholism by the power of God?

Comment: @Matthew - Good point. If that's true, then we should be able to find testimonial evidence of people being freed from drugs, alcohol, homosexuality, etc.

Comment: [1 Corinthians 6:9-11](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/l/r1/lp-e?q=1+Cor+6%3A9-11) answers your question, particularly verse 11

Comment: @4castle if you have an answer to a question, please post it as an answer. Comments are not for partial answers

Comment: It is not very hard to find many testimonials of people who have been "freed" from the homosexual lifestyle by the power of God.  For example... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Jernigan  Also here:  https://changedmovement.com/   I am in no way endorsing the variously militant Christian conversion therapy movements but I have personally witnessed the power of God victorious in this regard .  I have also witnessed the power of God quenched in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

Jesus gave the only example of unforgivable sin : the sin of blasphemy against the Holy Spirit.

Therefore if a self-confessed Christian defines anything else (other than that specific blasphemy) as 'sin' they automatically define that behaviour, conduct or activity as 'forgivable', by very definition.

But then they also define it as something not to be continued in , for 'he that is born of God does not practice sin'.

This is all a matter, of course, of those who (primarily) define themselves as 'Christian' and who also (secondly) define (any specific) activity as 'sin'.

> **All sins shall be forgiven unto the sons of men**, and blasphemies wherewith soever they shall blaspheme, But he that shall blaspheme against the Holy Ghost hath never forgiveness, but is in danger of eternal damnation: [Mark 3:27,28 KJV]

> Whosoever is born of God doth not commit [or, practice] sin; for his seed remaineth in him: and **he cannot sin**, because he is born of God. [1 John 3:9 KJV]

---

The question is asking about what is being defined as a 'desire' which is specifically dealt with in scripture, such as in Romans chapter 7.

But the specifics of Romans 7 require further treatment and further questions.

For 'desire' is not an outward action but an inward (and constitutional) instinct. Which Paul covers under the broad heading of 'coveting'.

In this respect it would have been more logical to have (first) asked the question as to whether self-identifying Christians perceive that 'sinful desires', generally (and indiscriminately) speaking, are 'reversed' by the influences of the Divine Spirit who is, personally, Holy.

Such as coveting other people's money, for example, something common to **all** humanity.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of [sanctification](https://www.ligonier.org/blog/what-sanctification/). That link quotes the Westminster Confession of Faith, which says sanctification is:

> the work of God’s free grace, whereby we are renewed in the whole man after the image of God, and are enabled more and more to die unto sin, and live unto righteousness.

Therefore I believe you are correct in your analysis, that Christians should expect to overcome sin in their lives - including sinful desires such as lust.

At the same time, there is a question - WHEN will we be sanctified?

The experience of generations of Christians is that sanctification does not occur all at once. Many Christians have lifelong battles with sin of many different kinds. In fact, this is key to the Christian life. Jesus says that the Christian life is about self-denial (Mark 8:34). We must constantly be putting to death the misdeeds of the body (Colossians 3:5).

The only thing we know for sure is that we will be transformed in the future once and for all. "Dear friends, now we are children of God, and what we will be has not yet been made known. But we know that when Christ appears, we shall be like him, for we shall see him as he is" (1 John 3:2).

There are some people who seem to experience a change in orientation, for example some of the testimonies on [Living Out](https://www.livingout.org/resources/stories/19/sean-and-gaby). But many people do not seem to experience a change.

I believe this is consistent with a belief that we are not promised complete sanctification in this life. We may need to struggle with issues of sin for our whole lives, but that doesn't mean progress isn't possible or there is no value in the struggle.